# Error in celluloid gem installation

Tags: ruby, bundler, celluloid

Recently I have update my rails version to `4.2.3` and ruby version to  `ruby-2.2.3`. After that when I do bundle it gives following error:

```
$ bundle
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching version metadata from http://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Could not find celluloid-0.16.1 in any of the sources
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 40):

Version `0.16.1` of the `celluloid` gem was [yanked](https://rubygems.org/gems/celluloid/versions) and is not available anymore. You will need to downgrade to `0.16.0` or upgrade to `0.17.x`. Run:

```
bundle update celluloid
```

Comment: you... sir.., saved my day ;)

Comment: @spickermann, i have tried this solution but did not help still heroku gives the same error.

Comment: @spickermann, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32312071/issue-while-deploying-ruby-app-on-heroku-bundler-failed

Here I define my question which you marked duplicate. 
The difference is here the error arises while bundle install 
And in my case the error arises while deploying app on heroku . 

Thanks

Comment: @QubaishBhatti: Is it really the same error (*Could not find celluloid-0.16.1 in any of the sources*)? If so, please ensure that the current version of celluloid in your `Gemfile.lock` is not `0.16.1` after you ran `bundle update celluloid` and that you did a git commit with the changed `Gemfile.lock`.

Comment: @spickermann, yeah you are right my gemfile.lock have celluloid version 0.16.1. Thanks I solved my problem :)