# Rails - Heroku push rejected, failed to comp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have issues pushing my Rails app to Heroku. Error for `git push heroku master`:

```
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using 1.9.7
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Could not find celluloid-0.16.1 in any of the sources
remote:        Bundler Output: Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Could not find celluloid-0.16.1 in any of the sources
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

Here's my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'

gem 'rails', '4.0.8'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.2.0.2'
gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.0'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.2'
gem 'faker', '1.1.2'
gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.6.4.1'
gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'rerun'
gem 'sinatra', :require => nil
gem 'gocardless_pro'
gem 'oauth2', '~> 1.0.0'
gem 'will_paginate',            '3.0.4'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.10'
gem 'simple_form'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

I tried running `gem dependency celluloid --reverse-dependencies`:

```
Gem celluloid-0.16.0
  benchmark_suite (>= 0, development)
  guard-rspec (>= 0, development)
  rake (>= 0, development)
  rspec (~> 2.14.1, development)
  rubocop (>= 0, development)
  timers (~> 4.0.0)
  Used by
    listen-2.10.1 (celluloid (~> 0.16.0))
```

I then tried `gem dependency listen --reverse-dependencies` which didn't really help:
`gem dependency listen --reverse-dependencies`

I'm not really sure where the issue comes from and what I can do about it. Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error in celluloid gem installtion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32182273/error-in-celluloid-gem-installtion)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like bundler not able to install `celluloid-0.16.1` gem. Repository of this gem hosted on github. Today github experiencing DDoS attack issue. You can find it [here](https://status.github.com/messages).

My suggestion is to try push to heroku again after some time.

Answer (score 0):

update only the celluloid gem:

```
bundle update celluloid
```