# Issue while deploying ruby app on heroku bundler failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

This is my gem file

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "2.1.1"
gem 'rails', "4.1.0"
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
#gem 'bootstrap-sass', '>= 3.0.0.0'

gem 'pg'
gem 'celluloid', '~> 0.16.0'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem "chargify_api_ares"
gem 'cancan'
gem 'rails_12factor'
gem 'devise'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'rolify'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'therubyracer', :platform=>:ruby
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'chosen-rails'
gem 'letsrate'
gem 'acts_as_commentable'
gem 'friendly_id'
gem 'sunspot_rails'
gem "nested_form"
gem 'haversine'
# BACKGROUND JOBS
gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'foreman'
gem 'rmagick', require: false
gem 'kaminari'
gem "geocoder"
gem 'jquery-validation-rails'
gem 'activemerchant'
gem 'ckeditor_rails'
gem 'roo'
gem 'spreadsheet'
gem 'httparty'
gem 'exception_notification'
gem 'jquery-placeholder-rails'
#uploading files via rails remote true forms
gem 'remotipart', '~> 1.2'
# gem for finding lat and long from address
gem 'geokit', '~> 1.8.4'

#for generating pdf 
gem 'pdfkit', '~> 0.8.0'

#for pagination
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0'
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'activerecord-session_store', github: 'rails/activerecord-session_store'
gem "cocoon"
gem "nokogiri"
#for calculating distance 
gem 'google_directions'
#for breadcrumb navigation
gem "breadcrumbs_on_rails"
# Fancybox
gem 'fancybox2-rails', '~> 0.2.8'
#meta_tags
gem 'meta-tags'
gem 'smarter_csv'
# site Maps SEO
gem 'sitemap_generator'
gem "sidekiq-cron", "~> 0.2.0"
#fog for amazon connectivity
gem 'fog'
gem 'stripe'
gem 'stripe_event'
gem 'countries', :require => 'iso3166'
gem 'unicorn'
# gem "rack-timeout"
gem 'urbanairship'
group :staging do
  gem 'thin'
  gem "wkhtmltopdf-heroku"
end
group :development do
  gem 'binding_of_caller', :platforms=>[:mri_19, :mri_20, :rbx]
  gem 'html2haml'
  gem 'hub', :require=>nil
  gem 'rails_layout'
  gem 'sunspot_solr' # optional pre-packaged Solr distribution for use in development
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'wkhtmltopdf'
end
group :development, :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem  'wkhtmltopdf-binary' #for pdfkit local
end
group :production do
  # We need this gem only deploying app on heroku
  gem "wkhtmltopdf-heroku"
end
gem "going_postal"
group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'database_cleaner', '1.0.1'
  gem 'email_spec'
end
```

I am facing this issue

```
    remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.1.1
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using 1.9.7
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Your Gemfile lists the gem wkhtmltopdf-heroku (>= 0) more than once.
remote:        You should probably keep only one of them.
remote:        While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Updating git://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store.git
remote:        Could not find celluloid-0.16.1 in any of the sources
remote:        Bundler Output: Your Gemfile lists the gem wkhtmltopdf-heroku (>= 0) more than once.
remote:        You should probably keep only one of them.
remote:        While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Updating git://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store.git
remote:        Could not find celluloid-0.16.1 in any of the sources
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy....
```

Please help me on this ... i am trying different solutions like
 - Bundle update 
 - change celluloid gem version

But did not help. I am not sure where i miss the thing or heroku is updated. 
I also follow this issue https://discussion.heroku.com/t/heroku-push-rejected-failed-to-install-gems-via-bundler/239 but don't know how to upgrade bundler version.

Thanks

Comment: "Your Gemfile lists the gem wkhtmltopdf-heroku (>= 0) more than once.
  You should probably keep only one of them". Check your Gemfile you have added this twice

Comment: Deploy your application with proper environment, currently its showing..  -- Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment

Comment: Yeah i know, I define gem one for stagging and one for production but seems it is not causing any issue while deploying on heroku. Thanks for your comment :)

Comment: @RajAdroit, yeah i am seeing this but don't know any solution. Could you please help me how i deploy with proper environments ?

Comment: @QubaishBhatti try this, heroku config:set BUNDLE_WITHOUT="development:test:staging"

Comment: @RajAdroit, i tried this but it did not help still the same error. Thanks for your help.